# autoinstall - using webhooks for reporting

Tags: curtin

[autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference) includes the option to report to a webhook:

```
reporting:
 hook:
  type: webhook
  endpoint: http://example.com/endpoint/path
  consumer_key: "ck_foo"
  consumer_secret: "cs_foo"
  token_key: "tk_foo"
  token_secret: "tk_secret"
  level: INFO
```

I tried to configure this, but to no avail. Since I'm not really familiar with webhooks, I first tried to get any info at all and set up this config:

```
reporting:
 hook:
  type: webhook
  endpoint: localhost:8000
```

I then set up netcat on my local server like this:

```
nc -l localhost 8000
```

But on this socket I get nothing at all. I'm not very sure how to consume this service, but I'd expect to see any data at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup [an http-echo-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57938/generic-http-server-that-just-dumps-post-requests) and added the `reporting` section to a config.  *When* the webhook reporting works, it appears to send one HTTP request for each log message generated.

For example, this line in the file `/var/log/installer/subiquity-server-debug.log`

```
2021-05-05 00:06:50,666 DEBUG root:39 finish: subiquity/Network/_send_update: SUCCESS: CHANGE ens192
```

corresponds with this HTTP request

```
--> POST / HTTP/1.1
--> Accept-Encoding: identity
--> Content-Length: 190
--> Host: REDACTED:8080
--> User-Agent: Curtin/21.2-7-gd49d35bc6
--> Content-Type: application/json
--> Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="24545438356422201711620173210", oauth_timestamp="1620173210", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="ck_foo", oauth_token="tk_foo", oauth_signature="cs_foo%26tk_secret"
--> Connection: close
-->
--> {"name": "subiquity/Network/_send_update", "description": "CHANGE ens192", "event_type": "finish", "origin": "curtin", "timestamp": 1620173210.6665578, "level": "DEBUG", "result": "SUCCESS"}
```

I tested originally with `subiquity` `20.04.3` and the HTTP server received **no data**, just like you observed.

I added the configuration to have `subiquity` update itself.  This resulted in using `subiquity` `21.04.2` and the HTTP server did receive messages.

Here is a partial config of what was tested

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  refresh-installer:
    update: yes
  reporting:
    mylistener:
      type: webhook
      endpoint: http://REDACTED:8080/
      consumer_key: "ck_foo"
      consumer_secret: "cs_foo"
      token_key: "tk_foo"
      token_secret: "tk_secret"
      level: INFO
```

**Other Notes**

- I do not see any [commits](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/commits/0ad21b7c96fae870632c632cd16a2e8807a00183/subiquity/server/controllers/reporting.py) or [bug fixes](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/releases) related to reporting or webhook, so I'm not certain what fixes it or how reliable it should be considered.
- Even though the level is set to `INFO`, the webhook is still sent messages for `DEBUG`.